# WCF 4.0, .NET 2.0 client and .NET types

Tags: c#, types, wcf, wcf-client

This is my scenario:

- WCF 4.0 service
- .NET 2.0 client (that consumes the above service)

I need, let's say, to pass an array of `NetworkInterfaces` (`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaces`) from the client to the service. A web reference `wcfReference` to WCF service has been added to the client side.

Service code:

```
public void StoreNetworkInterfaces(System.Net.NetworkInterfaces[] nwInterfaces)
{
...
}
```

Client code:

```
wcfService.StoreNetworkInterfaces(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaces.GetAllNetworkInterfaces());
```

I'm getting:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[]' to 'WindowsFormsApplication1.wcfReference.NetworkInterface[]'`

Same happens for any other types (.NET and non .NET types). I know this is the desired behaviour for a web service (interop) but the scope of my WCF is just serving to a client installer.

Manually changing proxy code after each Web Reference update is definitively not a good choice for this project.

Any help or approach suggestion would be very appreciated.

Greets

Answer (score 2):

A web-reference (2.0-style) doesn't have the "re-use types" option that full a WCF (3.0+) service-reference supports, so **if you use the tooling** you are going to have to accept the proxy types over the wire, and then transform them (perhaps AutoMapper) to/from the domain types.

Do not edit the reference file; that may be regenerated randomly.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Never heard about AutoMapper. I'll take a look. Anyway... would xml serialization be suitable for this scenario? Thanks again.

Comment: @HiseaSaw as suitable as any other... especially when talking 2.0.